# How to update an active directory using userform textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which loads data from text files contained in directories back into text boxes on the user interface.

What I want to achieve is:

1. if the user changes a text of one of the text boxes and then clicks an "Update" button, the old record and its holding directory should be deleted the new record, saved in a new directory.

The code I am using now is:

```
  Dim dtl = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Cake Orders\" & TextBox1.Text))

        'Delete the culled record
        Try
            If Directory.Exists(dtl.FullName) Then
                Dim oDirectory As New DirectoryInfo(dtl.FullName)
                If oDirectory.GetFiles.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each oFile As FileInfo In oDirectory.GetFiles
                        oFile.Delete()
                    Next
                End If
                If oDirectory.GetDirectories.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each oDir As DirectoryInfo In oDirectory.GetDirectories
                        oDir.Delete(True)
                    Next
                    dtl.Delete()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        'Continue to save the updated record
```

The above code just saves the current data in a new directory (which is fine), but does not delete the original directory like I want it to; that is to say that my code is not executing the above delete routine.

How can I achieve my objective? I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is that you find a way to walk around your problem, to get your program to do what you want it to.

Granted, some may provide you with some more advanced, Einstein-esque codes that will do what you want and by all means, I would encourage you try them out. In the meantime, why not consider this approach?

During the cull event when you load data from the root directory, why not save the name of your sub-directory to a redundant textbox so that your delete routine can ‘see’ it and execute the delete routine before the rest of your code, which you say works fine, runs?

This is to say:

```
 Dim dtl = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Cake Orders\" & RedundantTextbox.Text))
```

Surely, you would not be charged with finding a cheeky way to avoid being eaten alive by software programming which sometimes can be a brain-eating dinosaur.